# Headphone jack does not work in HP Pavilion G60-530us under Linux Mint 9

Tags: linux, audio, linux-mint, alsa, headphone-jack

After installing Linux Mint on my laptop, I found that plugging in a speaker to the headphone jack did not mute the speakers. I followed the instructions [here](http://monespaceperso.org/blog-en/2010/05/02/upgrade-alsa-1-0-23-on-ubuntu-lucid-lynx-10-04/) to upgrade my ALSA driver, and now my headphone jack doesn't even output any sound at all. Is there a known fix for this? Here is some information that will probably prove useful:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.23.
Compiled on Oct 16 2010 for kernel 2.6.32-21-generic (SMP).

$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Conexant CX20583 (Pebble HSF)
Codec: Intel G45 DEVCTG
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do. If there is more information that would be helpful, please tell me and I'll provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed some new ALSA drivers from Linuxant: http://www.linuxant.com/alsa-driver/, and after rebooting the sound worked exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems and tried linuxant, but for me it made the driver not work at all. After reinstalling all the original packages, what fixed it for me was adding
"options snd-hda-intel model=ideapad" to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Fix was found here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/680844

Configuration:

linux mint 10, amd64

$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 | grep Codec

Codec: Conexant CX20585

$ cat /proc/asound/version

Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.23.

$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf | grep snd-hda-intel

options snd-hda-intel model=ideapad